# Docker mysql using the existing /var/lib/mysql on host

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to run a Docker instance to use the existing databases saved in /var/lib/mysql on host.

I changed the ownership to 999:999, which are used in docker mysql instance.
Then I run the following commands to start the instance but the logs shows that it can't run successfully.

```
[root@centos7 ~]# systemctl stop mariadb
[root@centos7 ~]# docker run --name mysql -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
65bb99c11fb3f7d0c2f6c5be3f6f2de2b87d20bed49d83161636de2fa4d257ff
[root@centos7 ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
[root@centos7 ~]# docker logs mysql
2021-06-16 03:00:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
2021-06-16 03:00:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-06-16 03:00:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.134878Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) starting as process 1
2021-06-16T03:00:32.144828Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.144956Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.322903Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012530] [InnoDB] Unknown redo log format (104). Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ upgrading-downgrading.html.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.323132Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.721498Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.723771Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-06-16T03:00:32.724440Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-16T03:00:32.736532Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[root@centos7 ~]# ls -lnd /var/lib/mysql
drwxr-xr-x 6 999 999 290 Jun 16 11:00 /var/lib/mysql
[root@centos7 ~]# docker run --rm -it mysql bash
root@e56e88d268b8:/# grep mysql /etc/passwd
mysql:x:999:999::/home/mysql:/bin/sh
root@e56e88d268b8:/# grep mysql /etc/group
mysql:x:999:
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922023/mysql-8-0-unsupported-redo-log-format please check if this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be happened due to your mix of `mysql dababase` & `mariadb database`.

> systemctl stop mariadb

Above means your host's `/var/lib/mysql` is for mariadb, while `mysql:latest` of container run command means you are now using mysql for container solution.

So, what I suggest is also use [mariadb image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) for container, e.g.

```
docker run --name mysql -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mariadb
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. Thanks atline.

[root@centos7 ~]# docker exec -it c3b9efb368aa bash
root@c3b9efb368aa:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3

Comment: Great, you may accept the answer with "√“ rather than paste another answer to confirm it.